# row cache consuming all system memory

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I have a single machine with 128 Gb RAM running Cassandra.

Here is how I created my keyspace and column family, using CQL 3:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS Identification
  WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
  'DC1' : 1 };
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entitylookup (
  name varchar,
  value varchar,
  entity_id uuid,
  PRIMARY KEY (name, value, entity_id))
WITH
    caching=all
;
```

I have set `row_cache_size_in_mb=1000`, excepting rowcache to occupy 1 Gb outside heap.

I have left `row_cache_save_period=0` and didn't set `memory_allocator`.

I started Cassandra and started running my application on it. After some time running, even my entire keyspace having less than 10 Gb, All 128 Gb of machine RAM got allocated and cassandra stops.

If I set `row_cache_save_period=0`, I get no more than 10Gb allocated in machine RAM and the problem doesn't happen.

I am using Cassandra 2.0.7, almost everything in the config is using the defaults, except for listen_address, rpc_address.

Could it be a bug? Or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: OutOfMemoryError means the heap is full, rather than the OS memory is full. What is your heap size? What workload caused the OOME?

Comment: I am sorry, this was a mistake of mine, I checked the log again and there was no out of memory exception. I will edit the post.

Comment: Why does Cassandra stop? What is the last line in the log before it dies?